# Scylla certifications for admin/architects/developer

Tags: nosql, scylla

First, Thanks for Scylla university. While I am exploring Scylla university did not find any certifications courses for admin/developer and architects. Please help me if there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scylla University will continue to grow. We are working on developing and offering many more courses, so stay tuned.

At this time, Scylla does not have a certification program. Our focus is, first, on getting good content out to Scylla users. We are actively working on certification - both the standards and the training content - and expect to have it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Every 2-4 months you can find a blogpost / tweet re Scylla University (what's new, new courses/lessons, training days, LIVE university etc.).

Here a list of the recent (what's new) updates:
[Oct 2019](https://www.scylladb.com/2019/10/22/whats-new-at-scylla-university-new-data-modeling-course-certificates-training-day/)  |  [Mar 2020](https://www.scylladb.com/2020/03/19/whats-new-at-scylla-university-march-2020-update/)  |  [June 2020](https://www.scylladb.com/2020/06/23/scylla-university-updates-june-2020/)  |  [Feb 2021](https://www.scylladb.com/2021/02/16/whats-new-at-scylla-university-for-february-2021/)  |  [June 2021](https://www.scylladb.com/2021/06/03/whats-new-at-scylla-university-june-2021/)

As of Oct 2019, Scylla University does offer certificates. Recently [katacoda](https://katacoda.com/scylla) support was added.